# 2 text inputs fill the whole width not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<div class="row mb-3">
    <div class="col-6">
        <form autocomplete="off" action="/action_page.php">
            <div class="autocomplete" >
                <input type="text" id="startLocation" class="form-control" placeholder="von Bahnhof / Haltestelle / Adresse" tabindex="-1">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <input type="text"id="destination" class="form-control" placeholder="nach Bahnhof / Haltestelle / Adresse" tabindex="-1">
    </div>
</div>
```

I want my two text inputs to be the same with and toghther fill the total width. The Problem is the "startLocation does not have the correct width. I think its because its nested inside another element but I need the other element to have the class `autocompleted` so I don't know how to fix this.

Sorry If this is a stupid beginner question. Im new to html and bootstrap.

Comment: can you please share some jsfiddle or plunker, thats more better

Answer (score 0):

What is the "mb-3" class for in row? 
Did you mean md-3? Which you would only need to set column widths (if you're using bootstrap).
Open the developer tools and check the padding and margin around the form.  The form itself, and the nested div are probably taking up some space. Also the inputs have different parents so your styling might not be targeting the right selector.

Comment: I do mean mb-3. That ensures the padding with other elements around. The my div with class="col-6" has the right size however the form in it didn't had the same width as the div. I fixed it with setting it css width to 100%.